# Почему выдает ошибку Fatal error при использовании рекурсии?

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка:

```
<?php
/*Написать функцию которая рекурсивно выводит все делители переданого числа(для 21 это 7 и 3)*/

function printNumberDivisors(int $num, int $div=2){
    if($num==$div){
        return;
    }
    if($num%$div==0){
        echo "$div ";
    }

    return printNumberDivisors($num,$div++);
}

printNumberDivisors(21);
```

Выдает такую ошибку:
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in D:\OpenServer\domains\BranderPHPcourse\lesson4\Task4.php on line 12

Где я ошибся?

Comment: исправьте на ++$div

Comment: Спасибо! А почему постфиксный инкремент дал такой результат?

Comment: Потому что при использовании постфиксного инкремента сначала выполняется операция с переменной, а потом ее значение увеличивается. То есть при входе в рекурсию значение всегда остается прежним (изменится оно потом, после возврата рекурсивного вызова) и рекурсия уходит в бесконечность